# Android / Java - Seeking Drag and Drop GridView Example with textView

Tags: java, android, gridview, textview, android-launcher

I'm attempting to build a file manager containing a simple gridView which can be dragged and dropped - as well as the ability to rename each folder.

The closest I've been able to find thus far is this example:

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/improved-drag-drop-for-gridview/

However I am unable to figure out how to add a textView which can be dragged and dropped in addition to the tiles in the example.

Thus far I have tried this:

[Android / Java - Add textView to Drag-Drop GridView Tutorial / Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963115/add-text-to-drag-drop-gridview)

However I am wondering if anyone has seen an example of how this can be accomplished.

I imagine a drag and drop gridview with a textView would be a common implementation for either a file manager or a custom launcher - so I am surprised I have not been able to find any examples.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this lib and it have sample project also

https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful! Also - if you have a minute... (and would like an easy answer) I have a question related to the resource you provided. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964584/replacing-bitmap-with-drawable-in-drag-and-drop-example

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use the same library but i needed some more Customization. I have a nice start for a RecyclerView with a gridlayout view. Check it out on https://github.com/everlutions/recycler-drag-n-drop-example. It's my first github example so comments are more than welcome ^^.